# A simple question on spans

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am trying to show that if $span\{2x+y, y+z\}=span\{x, y, z\}$ then $z\in span\{2x+y, y+z\}$ where $x$ and $y$ are non-zero vectors.

Let $a, b, c, d, e \in \mathbb F$ where $\mathbb F$ is field of our vector space.

We can write $a(2x+y) + b(y+z) = cx + dy + ez$ by the equality of sets. However I could not write $z$ as a linear combination of $2x+y$ and $y+z$

I am so sorry if there is a mistake.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$z\in\text{span}(x,y,z)$, since $z=1z$, where $1$ is the multiplicative identity of $\Bbb F$.

Then, if $\text{span}(2x+y,y+z)=\text{span}(x,y,z)$, $z\in\text{span}(2x+y,y+z)$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The question ( it is not question of OP) is whether you can find a,b ?  I don't think its possible without knowing the field and how field act on V. But I'm not sure

Comment: You're right, we need something more, but I think even knowing the field we haven't got enough to obtain $a$ and $b$. The reason is that this statement is not for some particular vectors $x,y,z$; it's a general statement, so we can't operate with their coordinates or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

You know that $z\in\text{span}\{x,y,z\}\implies z\in\text{span}\{2x+y,y+z\}$ since both spans are identical (given).

Comment: Thank you so much!